# How to return 0 if strings do not match sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have these tables:

```
School
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      SchoolID       |     City         |     State        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       City1      |       State1     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       City2      |       State2     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |       City3      |       State3     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|


Teacher
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Location      |     TeacherID    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     City1 State1    |       123-A      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     City2 State2    |       123-B      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     City4 State4    |       123-C      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

So I'm trying to return a query like so by combining the city and state from the School table and checking which SchoolID is linked to which TeacherID:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      TeacherID      |     SchoolID     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       123-A         |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       123-B         |       2          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       123-C         |       0          |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Here is my code so far

```
SELECT Teacher.TeacherID as TeacherID,
  (
    SELECT School.SchoolID
    FROM School
    WHERE CONCAT(School.City, ' ', School.State) = Teacher.Location
  ) AS SchoolID
FROM Teacher
```

However, I get this returned instead:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      TeacherID      |     SchoolID     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       123-A         |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       123-B         |       2          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       123-C         |     null         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

So my question is how do I replace null with 0 when a query isn't found? I tried using:

```
SELECT IFNULL(School.SchoolID, 0)
```

but it just returns the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encapsule the query

```
SELECT Teacher.TeacherID as TeacherID,
  IFNULL((
    SELECT School.SchoolID
    FROM School
    WHERE CONCAT(School.City, ' ', School.State) = Teacher.Location
  ),0) AS SchoolID
FROM Teacher;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the IFNULL to the result of the subselect, not within the subselect:

```
    IFNULL((
        SELECT School.SchoolID
        FROM School
        WHERE CONCAT(School.City, ' ', School.State) = Teacher.Location
    ),0) AS SchoolID
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is easier with a `left join`

```
select t.TeacherID, ifnull(s.SchoolID,0)
from Teacher t
left join School s on concat(s.City, ' ', s.State) = t.Location
```